# Selecting from my database

Tags: php, mysql, database

Can anyone tell me why this code does not output all of the table info, only one name and email is displayed, and there are more than 1 in the table

```
<?
 $user_result = "select * from mytable;";
$qry = mysql_query($user_result) OR die(mysql_error());
$user_array = mysql_fetch_assoc($qry);


echo "<center>";
echo "<table CELLPADDING=10 border =1 >";
echo "<tr>";
echo  "<td>".$user_array['email']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$user_array['firstname']."</td>";

echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";

mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: Because you need to wrap `mysql_fetch_assoc($qry)` in while loop.

Comment: hahaha i am first FRED :D

Comment: Too funny, 2 seconds apart. Had a hard time finding my escape key ;-) ironic, isn't it.

Comment: and a suggestion: Do not use `<center>` tag. It is not accepted anymore in HTML5. Use `margin: auto;` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Seems as I was putting this together, other answers have been given; submitting anyway)

You need to use a loop. I'm using a `while` loop in the example below.

```
<?
$user_result = "select * from mytable;";
$qry = mysql_query($user_result) OR die(mysql_error());

   echo "<center>"; // these are deprecated btw. Use CSS
   echo "<table CELLPADDING=10 border =1 >";

   echo "<tr> <th>Email</th> <th>Name</th></tr>"; // added as column headers

while($user_array = mysql_fetch_array($qry))
 {

   echo "<tr>";
   echo  "<td>".$user_array['email']."</td>";
   echo "<td>".$user_array['firstname']."</td>";
   echo "</tr>";

}

   echo "</table>";
   echo "</center>"; // these are deprecated btw

mysql_close();
?>
```

---

**Footnotes:**

`mysql_*` functions deprecation notice:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php

This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and is not recommended for writing new code as it will be removed in the future. Instead, either the [**mysqli**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [**PDO_MySQL**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used. See also the [**MySQL API Overview**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) for further help while choosing a MySQL API.

These functions allow you to access MySQL database servers. More information about MySQL can be found at » http://www.mysql.com/.

Documentation for MySQL can be found at » http://dev.mysql.com/doc/.

Answer (score 1):

As some of the comments mentioned, you would need to loop through the result like this.

```
<?
$query = "select * from mytable";
$user_result = mysql_query($query) OR die(mysql_error());

echo "<center>";
echo "<table>";

while ($user_array = mysql_fetch_assoc($user_result)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $user_array['email'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $user_array['firstname'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
echo "</center>";

mysql_close();
?>
```

(I also switched around your variable names to avoid confusion between the query and the result of the query)

Answer (score 1):

Use a while loop -

```
echo "<center>";
echo "<table CELLPADDING=10 border =1 >";

while($user_array = mysql_fetch_assoc($qry))
{
     echo "<tr>"; 
     echo  "<td>".$user_array['email']."</td>";
     echo "<td>".$user_array['firstname']."</td>";
     echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
echo "</center>";
```